# rumors on PWM on m1 macbook air

Tags: display, macbook

i am planning to get a new m1 MacBook air base model please tell me that do MacBooks and all other laptops use PWM even the M1? I have heard it's bad please help me put here

Comment: [Pulse-Width Modulation??](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation)

Comment: Meh, this is the same question as https://superuser.com/questions/1621785/rumors-on-pwm-flickering-on-m1-macbook-air - closed as opinion-based. Your research on that one contains some very suspect "science".

Comment: Duplicate of [rumors on PWM flickering on M1 macbook air](https://superuser.com/questions/1621785/rumors-on-pwm-flickering-on-m1-macbook-air)

Comment: We don't work with "rumors" or opinions of things. If you have a real problem using it then we might be able to help, but guessing what might be bad for you is an impossible task. The only way you're going to find out is to find one you can try out, or to find someone with the same sensitivities which is not a job for this kind of Q&A site. Many laptops *do* indeed use PWM, but listing all of them and their specifications is a mammoth task, again not something that suits this kind of site. PWM is often used as a power saving feature, something that is not surprising in a laptop.